# How to minimize to system tray in C

Tags: c, windows, winapi

How can I minimize my app to the system tray as soon as it starts in C?

I am new to C.

Thanks.

Comment: What UI framework are you using? Is it WinAPI?

Answer (score 2):

Are you talking about Windows and the taskbar status area? If so, check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762159.aspx for the `Shell_NotifyIcon` function. There are plenty of references, and even some samples linked on how to use it.

Also `Notifications and the Notification Area`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee330740.aspx

Comment: Yes windows and taskbar status are (system tray/ right corner). I have no idea how to implement that in my simple C program though. If you could give me a working example from a simple "hello world" script persepctive lets say I should be able to use it.

Comment: @luacoder: Lets say you should be able to read the material I just pointed you to, and come with your own simple 'script' that does what you want.

Answer (score 1):

C, all by itself, is not capable of doing what you want. The language was designed to work on as many possible architectures as possible (microwave ovens ... air bag systems ... mouse movement control ...) and not all such architectures know what a "system tray" is.

You need to use specific libraries (which augment the capabilities of Standard C). There are lots and lots (and lots) of external libraries. Most libraries to do the same thing on different platforms are not compatible between each other ... so we need to know what is the target of your code: Windows? Windows Vista? DOS? microwave oven? sattelite solar panel deployer? ... :-)

Comment: 'extensions' does not seem to be the right word, made my think of language extensions...

Comment: Thanks @K-ballo, you're right ... changed "extensions" to "[external] libraries"

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Definitely windows (XP and Win7). :) And if you please also could direct me to a full example page so I can implement it because I am new to C. I have of course looked at the Shell_Notification page many times except I have no idea how to use it.

Comment: I don't know how to use the Windows libraries, but I think [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fw5abdx6.aspx) has good documentation: the few times I needed something for Windows, it was enough.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a window but don't show it.
2. Use `Shell_NotifyIcon` to create the icon in the notification area.

In order to perform step 2 you will need the window created in step 1.

If you have never programmed in C before and never used the Win32 API before this is an ambitious first project. First of all you should master the basics of showing windows, programming a message loop, handling messages etc. I recommend [Programming Windows by Petzold](http://www.charlespetzold.com/pw5/).

Comment: No, that's not a window. A window is something created by calling CreateWindow. Shell_NotifyIcon requires a window. Have you ever called CreateWindow?

Comment: No not yet. I am new to it. :)

Comment: Take my advice and start with something more basic. Get Petzold's book and learn what a window is, what a message loop is, how to handle messages and so on. Then take it from there. If you don't get the basics right to begin with you'll be struggling forever more.

Comment: OK, if you don't want to learn how to do it yourself, you'd better hope somebody is prepared to do it for you. But I can't help you there, you are quite right about that.